# Anonymizing postal addresses?

Tags: geocoding, gis-principle

I want to create an archive of mail I receive and send. Part of my goal is to provide public statistics about this archive, like a world-map with a pin for each location I sent mail to or received mail from. In order to protect the identities of those I receive mail from and send mail to, I would like to anonymize the addresses. This is, instead of pointing to the exact address mail went to, the pin should be placed over the general region the address is in. This region should follow administrative divisions so people have an idea where the mail went to.

The word “region” is intentionally fuzzy as I am not sure what these regions should be. Equating regions to countries is coarse for the statistics I would like to provide. I thought about using ISO 3166-2 codes for the regions, which has the advantage of a standardized and short textual representation, but I haven't found a dataset that resolves ISO 3166-2 codes to coordinates yet.

For instance, when I send mail to *Deutscher Bundestag, Platz der Republik 1, 11011 Berlin, Germany*, an anonymized address could look like this, from fine to coarse:

- 11011 Berlin, Germany
- Mitte, Berlin, Germany
- Berlin, Germany / DE-BE
- Germany

Is there a free set of data points that I could use for these anonymized addresses? The dataset should contain for each region:

- The English or local name of the region
- A pair of coordinates in the center of the region
- optionally a short, unique textual representation of the region

It should be obvious for a third party what region is meant when provided with the name.

Comment: geocode locality example http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=Deutscher%20Bundestag,%20Platz%20der%20Republik%201,%2011011%20Berlin,%20Germany

Comment: GEOMETRIC_CENTER http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=%201,%2011011%20Berlin,%20Germany

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a Geocoding service like [nominatim](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/). It classifies data based on admin level so that you can choose the level upto which you can anonymize.

[image]

The service is free and the data is under open database license so you can use it as you like. depending on places local names are also available.
[image].